# back history link + #target on previous page

Tags: html

I am not sure how to do this and if this is possible?

I need to have a back link *i.e.* `history` go -1

But I also need to go to a certain part of the other page which has a target *i.e.* `#search-target`

(The simple way is to have it as `local-events-search.html#search-target` but I can’t get that to work as I'm using a database so won't know what page they are on so want to use back `history` + `#search-target`)

I've tried this but just get errors so not sure how to get around it

```js
function testss() {
  location.replace("#search-target");
  history.back();
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="active-top-menu"><a onClick="test();" class="dark-grey-panel">Back</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope you can advise.

Thanks

Tim

Comment: *I’m using a database so won’t know what page they are on* What has using a database go to do with not knowing the page they're on?

Comment: is there away to add #search-target too<a HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)" class="dark-grey-panel">Back</a>